# Why are my two apache2 virtualhosts pointing to the same directory?

Tags: apache2, ubuntu-20.04

I have two virtual hosts setup on my Ubuntu 20.04 Apache2 webserver.

example2.domain.com.conf

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/Dev
ServerName example2.domain.com
ServerAlias example2.domain.com

<Directory /var/www/Dev/>
Options FollowSymlinks
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

example.domain.com.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

DocumentRoot /var/www/example
ServerName example.domain.com
ServerAlias example.domain.com

<Directory /var/www/example/>
Options FollowSymlinks
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

Redirect permanent / https://example.domain.com/

</VirtualHost>
```

and finally: example.domain.com-le-ssl.conf

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>

DocumentRoot /var/www/example
ServerName example.domain.com
ServerAlias example.domain.com

<Directory /var/www/example/>
Options FollowSymlinks
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined


SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.domain.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.domain.com/privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

/etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 example2
```

Ok, so when I go to example2.domain.com it shows the example2 url but displays the files from example.domain.com. example.domain.com works just fine.

What gives?

Comment: Silly question, but have you confirmed that the configuration file(s) is/are enabled and that Apache has been reloaded? 

Comment: Yep. All enabled and Apache reloaded. Server updated and rebooted too just to make sure. And then triple checked it all again. Thanks for commenting!